# Macro go to a folder and delete sheets entered by user in all XLS sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my working code, I just want user to prompt for tab name, so that user can pick which tab to delete:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
      wb.Worksheets(2).Delete

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Be glad to help if you can post what you have so far

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This isn't a code writing service, give it a shot, use the macro recorder to get some basics then come back with a specific issue if you get stuck.

Comment: It won't let me add the code, length is too long

Comment: @user3860954 Don't add it as a comment, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29398340/edit) the code into your question

Comment: Please see the code now

Comment: instead of `wb.Worksheets(2).Delete` you want to present a list of worksheets to the user, then delete the one he chooses?

Comment: Freeman I want user to enter list of tab names one or more that he like to delete, sheet2 could be named Rawdata, so for example in 10 excel sheets user want to delete all the tabs that named Rawdata, and newsheet

Answer (score 1):

Add these variables (or similar) to the top of your code.

```
Dim DelSheet as string
Dim sht as worksheet
```

Get the sheet name - this is an example, you can get it from the user however you want

```
DelSheet = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the name of the sheet to delete")
```

Modify this portion of your code, above. Leave the rest as is, since it seems to be working ok.

```
Do While myFile <> ""
  'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

  'this loop isn't particularly efficient, but it prevents attempting
  'deletion of the sheet if that sheet doesn't exist in the wb
  'you could wrap the code in an "On Error..." block instead
  for each sht in wb.sheets
    if sht.name = DelSheet then
      wb.Worksheets(DelSheet).Delete
    endif
  next

  'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: WebMan I am getting error : Object doesn't support for  "For Each sht In wb "   line

Comment: `For each sht in wb.sheets` --- my bad.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope so to. If you accept an answer (either, since they're nearly identical), that will help people find good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

FreeMan's answer one step further (with multiple sheets to be deleted).

### New variables

```
Dim DelSheets() As String 'array
Dim intDelSheetCount As Integer
Dim DelSht As Variant
```

### New loop for user promt

```
'ask user multiple times, which sheets he wants to delete
Do
ReDim Preserve DelSheets(intDelSheetCount)
DelSheets(intDelSheetCount) = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the name of the sheet to delete")
intMsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to type more sheets to be deleted?", vbYesNo)
intDelSheetCount = intDelSheetCount + 1
Loop While intMsgBoxAnswer = 6 'while the answer is YES
```

### Deletion loop

```
  For Each sht In wb.Sheets
    For Each DelSht In DelSheets
        If sht.Name = DelSht Then
          DelSht.Delete
        End If
    Next DelSht
  Next
```

### Additional settings

To get rid of the Excel popup question, if you are super sure if you want to delete the sheet, you can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the beginning of the sub.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is a great idea